# Android RecyclerView's parent onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a `CardView` that has some children and also a `RecyclerView` with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. I have `onClickListener` on this `CardView` and it works fine until I click on the `RecyclerView`. Only `CheckBox`es in its items **need** to be clickable. Could you please tell me how I make it works? Preferably in Kotlin

Here is a representing image of my layout:

[image: Representing image]

Comment: You can disable checkbox and make the complete row of the recyclerview non-clickable. Over the top, make the CardView clickable .

Comment: what about adding another click listener to the recyclerView with the same code as the click listener of the cardView

Comment: @Kaido, if you mean just `recycler.setOnClickListener { ... }`, then it doesn't work. Setting a click listener for each child - the same. @skRana, it's neccesarry for me to have the checkboxes enabled and clickable